# How to filter Django BooleanFields and display the results in a template

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

Brand new to Python/Django and have hit a wall trying to figure out how to only show posts marked as `True` in certain parts of the same template.

For eg. I have a blog, the User can make posts but I want the posts marked as `science_post`, using a Django `BooleanField`, to be displayed separately from the rest of the blog posts.

**Here's what I have for my Post model:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    content = models.TextField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    picture_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=True)
    displayed_author = models.CharField(max_length=25, default=True)
    shortquote = models.TextField()
    reference_title = models.ManyToManyField(References)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    science_post = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("detail", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_love_url(self):
        return reverse("love", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    @property
    def comments(self):
        return self.comment_set.all()

    @property
    def get_comment_count(self):
        return self.comment_set.all().count()

    @property
    def get_view_count(self):
        return self.postview_set.all().count()

    @property
    def get_love_count(self):
        return self.love_set.all().count()
```

My idea was to simply filter out the posts marked `science_post` in the template using something along the lines of

```
{% if science_post %}
SHOW SCIENCE POST CONTENT HERE
{% endif %}
```

...But this returns nothing. Any help or a point in the right direction with this would be great. And if any additional info is needed, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Share also you views.py. What have you already tried to do?

Answer (score 3):

In order to realize two seperate displays of posts you should use two seperate queries in the backend instead of seperating them using if-statements in the frontend.

Try passing two QuerySets to your template, using two seperate queries where you filter the different kinds of posts:

```py
...
science = Post.objects.filter(science_post=True)
non_science = Post.objects.filter(science_post=False)
...
```

And then render them seperately in your template:

```html
...
{% for post in science_post %}
SHOW SCIENCE POST CONTENT HERE
{% endfor %}
...
{% for post in non_science %}
SHOW NON-SCIENCE POST CONTENT HERE
{% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Faraz. This has definitely pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: You're very welcome Delroy! Would you mind marking the answer as the solution?

Comment: @DelroyBrown i think there was no notification for you regarding my last comment, so im trying it with a ping now